# What are the effects of Jigsaw for Android?

Tags: java, android, java-platform-module-system

I was reading through the recent changes in the [Junit-Lambda](https://github.com/junit-team/junit-lambda/wiki) wiki when I came across [this comment](https://github.com/junit-team/junit-lambda/wiki/Suggestions-for-JUnit-Lambda/_compare/de65fe4%5E...de65fe4).

> Should we consider Jigsaw for modularization?
>
> [...] requiring Jigsaw in the core code would mean JUnit wouldn't work on Android

I'm wondering what exactly would break when Jigsaw would be applied to Android?

Will libraries after jdk9 not work any longer on Android?

Will libraries developed with Android in mind be usable with "Jigsawed" code?

Googling this brings up all kinds of apps, so that doesn't help.

Comment: Here you go bro, http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/04/how-java-9-and-project-jigsaw-may-break-your-code.html